# gps alwasy in searching but never lock it

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing android using locationClient with the provide code in this link
http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

The interval for each onLocationChanged call is 5 sec. 
When ever this method is called, I get a gps icon in my notification bar saying "searching gps......".  then location is updated.

But it never lock it.
When I use the built-in google map app, it starts off flashing the icon (seaching gps location....), then after a few second it locks the current location and the icon is no longer flashing but appeared to be a solid gps icon.

What dose it mean when it locks and icon its solid ?
Basically, I want the updated location to be accurate as possible and update as often

Comment: When the dot is solid, you can obtain location information. While it is blinking, you would get nothing, really. It is how GPS work. They need to connect to a number of satellites to find a fix, and when they do, the dot is going to be solid. That will happen most of the times when the app isn't working (and you have just started it), because keeping it connected drains your battery.

Comment: In my app, after the flashing, a location is updated from the onLocationChanged method. But never go solid.  How should it work ?
Should it be like the google map, always solid ? which seems to be reasonable to me.  But how ?

Comment: Are you trying your app indoors? You need to be outside so the GPS can work.

Comment: its outside. The location gets updated every 5 sec and marker is set to that location, which is cool.  But the gps icon is never fix(locked) but always flashing when onLocationChanged method is called.  I read some article about finding satellites and locking the location.  But its all about locationManger class stuff.  Dose the finding satellites helps the locking ? 
Is my app keeping on finding satellite every 5 sec and thats why is flashing ?

Comment: If it does lock and then starts blinking again, you're doing something wrong. But if it doesn't get solid at all, I'd say it's the device. I've encountered devices that have issues in the city (around buildings, etc.) and need more time to get location fix properly (if at all). On a field without any disturbance I've seen it work decently, though. All in all, just give it a lot of time (like 20 mins or so). If that doesn't work, then it might be the device.

Comment: Does it mean that, every call onLocationChanged would have a chance to get a location fix and solid icon ? Just to be sure, I am dealing with the new google api, its not the locationManger from android

Comment: onLocationChanged just gets the location at that time (I believe so, check documentation). I haven't used the new API, though, (don't want to rely on Google for the app I'm doing currently), so I cannot help you with that. However, what I know about it is that it allows tracking regardless of where you are (uses all the sensors accordingly). So I can only imagine it gets location from different providers. ALl in all, if you don't get a fix from the GPS outside, you can't rely on your location to be accurate.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49540/discussion-between-justwe-and-yordan-lyubenov)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After increasing the location update rate to 2 sec interval and 1 sec fastest interval.  Also, added LocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(Listener) to the onStop() like this

```
protected void onStop() {
    mLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(MainActivity.this);
    mLocationClient.disconnect();       
    super.onStop();
}
```

Followed, I uninstalled and reinstalled the app with GPS turn on.  This time, I was be able to have a GPS lock after around 5 seconds searching.

Thanks to Yordan Lyubenov's patiently help.